# Does Goldreich-Levin algorithm for finding large Fourier coefficients have time complexity upper bound = sample complexity upper bound?

Tags: time-complexity, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis, sample-complexity

I'm currently working on finding better bounds for Goldreich-Levin algorithm for estimating large Fourier coefficients of a boolean function.

I was surprised seeing that the upper bounds for time complexity and sample complexity is exactly the same, do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: They are not exactly the same, they differ by (at least) a multiplicative constant.

Comment: Here is another problem illustrating this phenomenon: estimating the sum of an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @YuvalFilmus, I'm wondering if this also generalizes to Goldreich-Levin on the torus $\mathbb{F}_p$ (categorical instead of boolean domain)?